# Adobe API to convert Office documents to PDF

Tags: pdf

**Is there any API available by Adobe that would enable me to convert Office Documents (docx, xlsx, pptx, etc.) files to a PDF file format?**

I would prefer to use .NET to do so, but if I have to I can resort to C/C++.

I've already tried using Adobe SDK, but it seems to me it works to automate the Acrobat application instead of giving me access to underlying functionality. If it's possible and anyone would care to give me an example, I'd be very thankful - after many hours googling it I was unable to find a good answer (a lot of samples doing the contrary, though - converting from PDF to Word).

One last thing, I need it to be an library from Adobe. So, PDFCreator, BCL EasyPDF, Aspose.Words/Cells/Slides etc., unfortunately, won't help me.

**UPDATE 1:**

I decided to ask this question in the forum because, first, I can't believe that Adobe wouldn't have a library to do this; Of course, it may be the case, but it's very strange.

**UPDATE 2:**

I also looked already into `AdobePDFMakerX.Word` interface. I tried calling the `CreatePDF(string in, string out)` interface, but to no avail. It always returns `false`, and there is no error description that I can use.

Comment: Can't you print it to adobe acrobat?

Comment: @dmaik, not sure what you mean, but I need it to be automated by an application.

Comment: When you are using office tools version 2007 and up, you could save as pdf (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/save-as-pdf-HA010064992.aspx). You can automate this from .net, but you don't use acrobat. Can't help you with exact details, since I am on a mac right now...

Comment: @dmaij, no problem, I'll look into it as an alternative. However, I needed to identify a solution from Adobe itself. But I'm really beginning to doubt its existence.

Comment: I have no doubt it exists, but the question is whether it is usable. I know you can install acrobat as printer driver, piping you print output to a pdf (like cutepdf etc). They probably have a great API to create pdf too, but I haven't used it (mostly because the other solutions are friendlier to implement). Good luck anyway.

Comment: @dmaij, with Adobe Pro you get a very nice API to create PDF from scratch, but that's not really my scenario. The printer would be my last possibility, but the absence of documentation and samples is enough to end the proof-of-concept I was building. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

want to convert doc file to pdf file using [Adobe pdf service api](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/document-services/index.html#get-createPDF-status:%7E:text=tables%20and%20figures-,Create,-%3A)

In short it has two parts:

1. make a post request ( providing require parameters  ) and from header take x-request-id
2. make a get request ( providing require parameters  ) and as responce you will get your pdf documet

it is working fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Aspose.Words didn't work for you? I tested the below code sample and works fine.

```
string filePdf  = @"D:\\Projects\\original.pdf";
string fileDocX = @"D:\\Projects\\New.docx";

Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(fileDocX);
doc.Save(filePdf, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf);
```